# Get a no matches [DELETE] error by using Anguarjs with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Creating and viewing objects go well.
But when I attempt to add a function of DELETE. It responses a error:

```
Started DELETE "/api/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-21 01:15:32 +1000
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/api/items"):
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in
```

I have set the resource for the items and could be found in the routing table

```
namespace :api do
  resources :items, defaults: {format: :json}
end

api_capsule GET /api/capsules/:id(.:format)      api/items#show {:format=>:json}
            PATCH    /api/items/:id(.:format)    api/items#update {:format=>:json}
            PUT      /api/items/:id(.:format)    api/items#update {:format=>:json}
            DELETE   /api/items/:id(.:format)    api/items#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

The following is the method of DELETE:

```
application.js.coffee

$scope.delete = ($index) ->
$scope.items[$index].$remove()
$scope.items.splice($index, 1)

controller.rb
def destroy
  respond_with current_user.items.destroy(params[:id])
end
```

Does any one know what'r wrong with these codes

Comment: You should edit your question title to refer to AngularJS, not Anguarjs - the misspelling is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the rails console output, you're trying to send a delete request to `/api/items`, when you should be sending it to `/api/items/:id`.

You're asking rails to delete a collection rather than an individual item, and rails is correctly informing you that the route does not exist.

Make sure the ID that you're trying to remove is actually set and/or used in your AngularJS controller action.

Make sure that `$scop.items[$index]` actually has an ID as it's building the URL incorrectly, and make sure that the `splice` call isn't being executed before the API request is being executed (possible given that the DELETE request will be async)